# Is there anyway to write server side nodejs in jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

Is there anyway to write server side `nodejs` code (like down code) in jade file or other template engines? (or without template engines):

```
extends layout

block content
  p Welcome to #{title}
  <!-- Here is some nodejs program that get data from database --!>
  <!-- These code not rendered/write in html output file --!>
  h1 = <!-- Fetched data from database --!>
```

Comment: No. You are supposed to write application code (like fetching data from database) in your server code, and then feed the results of that in your template.

Answer (score 2):

NO you cannot use JADE on the server side. JADE is a templating engine which can be used to write Front-end code. You can use javascript itself to write the server side code in NodeJS.

Answer (score -1):

Jade is just a templating engine that turns short-hand HTML into full-length HTML.  It is not a substitute for javascript.

However, there are javascript replacements such as CoffeeScript which look like Jade for JS.

So, check out coffeescript.